# Do time-based workflow field updates fire record-triggered Flows?

Tags: visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

Based on my tests apparently the answer is an unexpected no, but when a time-based WF executes do record-triggered Flows fire in cascade? For example, when a WF rule on Event executes a time-dependent action to update the Event itself do Flows that trigger on update of Event fire?

The "re-evaluate workflows" option was selected on the time-based Field Update action in my test.

See the debug logs as proof of my experiment:

[image]

If I update the record manually the corresponding Flows get fired and they show up in the debug logs:

[image]

Comment: per https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&type=5, triggers execute when time-based actions fire so I don't see why automation (wfr, pb, flows) wouldn't execute upon DML

Comment: @cropredy See the attached debug logs. Flows don't seem to be getting triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eN8vAAE) that prevents Process Builder (and apparently Flows) from triggering when a TBWF rule runs. I ended up converting my Flow into an Apex trigger.